# CSS loads in IE7, but is displayed as no CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I got a problem on my Website http://achensee.info/ when loading in IE7.

At first, everything works perfect, and you can see the correct styles for the header and some HTML elements. However, after the main stylesheet and a little time later, IE7 strips all styles from the Website and displays it without CSS.

So, the files are loaded, but applied. Is this a common problem, or is there a way to fix this?

Could it be that too many styles cause the IE7 to crash the CSS view?

Thanks for your help and greetings from Austria :)

Comment: could it be the super old ie8.js include that you're using? because that is specific to IE7 and lower, and i believe it uses an AJAX call to your CSS files to reapply all styles.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was testing all the CSS files, removing them one after the other, and the IE7 worked without one of them - but also works with the CSS file included and the ie8.js removed. Could you post this as an answer please?

Comment: Yeah. Needed the Answer for your rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your call to the ie8.js file. It uses an AJAX call to your CSS files to reapply all styles, but its probably broken (as it never got past beta stage and was last touched in April of 2010).